# How to initiate a message transfer from an External program by sending the Id of the vehicle to veins

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am working on a program where I send the vehicle id from my program and in the TraCIScenarioManager I will be able to get the cModule associated with the vehicle Id if it has been already added in the simulation. I would like to initiate message transfer from this node. How can I do it making use of the cModule?

Comment: The manager module you mention has a list of all instantiated nodes, accessible by their ID. This should fit your use case nicely.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sir. I have the map of nodes from which I could I extract the exact node corresponding to the vehicle Id. However, with this node/cmodule how can I access the application layer to call the handleselfmsg function to trigger a message transfer?